# DataTable ServerSide scrollX not working and header table not aligned with table body

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

Greatings,

Maybe my question is very basic, but I have some problem when doing that. My DataTable Couldn't do ScrollX, and when I add scrollX : true, the align with thead and tbody not match.

I'm not using own CSS, I'm just use some css from ElaAdmin, bootstrap, and datatable. the bootstrap and datatable I attach from cdn.

in table tag i just use style like this

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" style="width:100%">
```

and that from javascript

```
<script>
    (function($){
       var s = $('#example').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            
            "ajax" : {
                url:"{{ route('example.index') }}",
                type: "GET",
            },
            "columns":[
                {data:'No', name:'PH.No', searchable:true},
                {data:'col1', name:'PH.col1', searchable:true},
                {data:'col2', name:'PL.col2', searchable:true},
                {data:'col3', name:'PL.col3', searchable:true},
                {data:'col4', name:'PL.col4', searchable:true},
                
            ],
            "order":[[0, 'desc']],

            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var input = document.createElement("input");
                    $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty()).on('change', function () {
                        column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                    });
                });
            },
        });
        
        
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

but, when I remove the scrollX:true, the align from thead and tbody was normal. and when I add scrollX, the scroll not apear and the align is not match.

Thankyou. I hope anybody can help me with this problem

Comment: What will be happened if you remove style="width:100%" from table

Comment: Thanks for your reply,The table couldn't view in page width, I need to scroll the page browser to see the search column of datatable. Do I need upload it to other source?

Answer (score 0):

Remove table-sm class in table element will fix the alignment issue.
If you must use table-sm class, write your own instead. do not change the padding for x-axis in td tag so the alignment calculation wont mess up.

```
.table-sm-custom td{
   padding-top:3px;
   padding-bottom:3px;
}
```